# Failed to execute "atlas-run-standalone --product jira "

Tags: maven, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

### I am new to atlassian-plugin-sdk, while running the command atlas-run-standalone --product jira, I am getting the following error

```
C:\Users\aaaaa>atlas-run-standalone --product jira

Executing: "D:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin\mvn.bat" com.atlassia
n.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:5.0.13:run-standalone -gs D:\atlassian-plugin-
sdk\apache-maven-3.2.1/conf/settings.xml -Dproduct=jira

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethrea
ded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-amps-plugin:5.0.13:run-standalone (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/atlassian/plugins
/rest/atlassian-rest-common/2.9.2-m01/atlassian-rest-common-2.9.2-m01.pom
Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/sun/jersey/contri
bs/wadl-resourcedoc-doclet/1.8-atlassian-8/wadl-resourcedoc-doclet-1.8-atlassian
-8.pom

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.018 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-20T10:27:34+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/23M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:5.0.13:run-standalone (default-cli) on project standalone-pom:
Execution default-cli of goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:5.0.13:run-standalone failed: Plugin com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:5.0.13 
or one of itsdependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:jar:5.0.13 -> 
com.atlassian.plugins.rest:atlassian-rest-doclet:jar:2.9.2 -> com.atlassian.jersey:atlassian-jersey-restdoc:jar:1.0.3 ->
com.atlassian.plugins.rest:atlassian-rest-common:jar:2.9.2-m01: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.atlassian.plugins.rest:atlassian-rest-common:jar:2.9.2-m01:
Could not transfer artifact com.atlassian.plugins.rest:atlassian-rest-common:pom:2.9.2-m01 from/to atlassian-public (https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public): 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unableto find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

[ERROR][ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException



C:\Users\aaaa>atlas-version

ATLAS Version:    5.0.13
ATLAS Home:       D:\atlassian-plugin-sdk
ATLAS Scripts:    D:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\bin
ATLAS Maven Home: D:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven-3.2.1
--------
Executing: "D:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin\mvn.bat" --version -g
s D:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven-3.2.1/conf/settings.xml
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T23:07:5
2+05:30)
Maven home: D:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.7.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

Please help me in solving this issue
Note: I have changed my proxy setting in setting.xml in maven, but its of no use,
I am getting the same error again and again

Answer (score 0):

I guess I replied to your question on answers.atlassian.com and here the answer will be the same: https://maven.atlassian.com is not trusted by your Java.

Here is what you need to make ti trusted:

**Download the certificate manually**
This depends on what browser you are using. For IE7, you need to browse to the website (eg. https://maven.atlassian.com) then:

- Right click on the page and access its Properties menu
- Click on the Certificates button
- Click on the Details Tab
- Choose Copy to File
- You will be taken to the Certificate Export Wizard, click next
- Choose a format of the certificate that you would like to choose then
  save the certificate to a directory of your choice.

**Install the certificate to your keystore**
You can use Java's keytool command to import it to your keystore, for example:

```
keytool -import -file myCertificate.cer -keystore myKeystor
```

Source: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Unable+to+Install+Plugin+Due+to+Maven+SSL